# Can I create an image of the system repair disk in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore, disk-image

I am running windows 7 in my desktop pc but unfortunately my DVD writer has stopped working. So my question is : can I somehow create an image of the system restore disk so that I will be able to burn it it into an actual disk sometime else ?

To avoid confusion: I do not have any physical system restore disk with me, and what I am trying is to create an image of the same.

Comment: I would suggest Windows 7 Disk-USB tool, but that seems not to help here. Is it possible you could make an iso of the disk and burn in to a usb for future use?

Comment: If you're just trying to make the System Repair Disk, you can make that from *any* Windows 7 machine, at any time, it doesn't have to be yours.  You can also use a Windows 7 install disk to restore an image backup.

Comment: @Moab yeah i know that

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 will they be same

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ISO file from the System Restore image and save it to a USB flash drive or external hard drive to be copied onto a DVD at a later point in time. There are many tools available to do this but I personally prefer to use [ActiveISO Burner](http://www.ntfs.com/iso-burning.htm).

You can alternatively use a USB flash drive as the System Repair source altogether eliminating the need for DVD completely by booting directly from the flash drive.